# How can I know which function or file and which line called a function?

Tags: c++, c, function

**For example**

```
void MyFunction()
{
    printf( "This function is called by %s in file %s on line $i.\n", func, file, line ); // Where func, file and lines should be replaced
}

int main()
{
    MyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit the link you pasted is not the answer to this question

Comment: Pick a language! These are not recommended declarators in C.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you might use [backtrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) to dump the stack:

> ```
>    backtrace() returns a backtrace for the calling program, in the array
>    pointed to by buffer.  A backtrace is the series of currently active
>    function calls for the program.  Each item in the array pointed to by
>    buffer is of type void *, and is the return address from the
>    corresponding stack frame.  The size argument specifies the maximum
>    number of addresses that can be stored in buffer.  If the backtrace
>    is larger than size, then the addresses corresponding to the size
>    most recent function calls are returned; to obtain the complete
>    backtrace, make sure that buffer and size are large enough.
> ```